# Global Protect not able to change Portal address

Tags: vpn

My laptop has Global Protect installed, but settings does not have an edit, add or delete button on the general tab to allow me to change the portal address.

This I need to do and I am scratching my head as to where Global Protect saves the VPN address or if need be remove the file so I can enter it in again through the UI

Answer (score 0):

May I know how many portals have you added in Global Protect?

If there is only one connected portal in General tab, then Delete and Edit buttons should be grey out. But the Add button can be clicked and a new portal address can be added. Then you can add/delete/edit this portal.

Attaching my test for your reference(my GP version is 5.1.5-20)

[result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vzqR.jpg)

[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfMlo.jpg)

Comment: Problem I have is in general tab I have none of the buttons.